# Audiobook about an alien disguised as a human trying to defend the Earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens, audio-book

I remember listening to an audiobook where an alien came to Earth in a talking spaceship to escape from alien pursuers. The spaceship left to distract the other aliens. He changed his features to look human and survived by changing objects into gold. Possibly, he got a girl pregnant.

He realized the hostile aliens now know about the Earth and would return to invade someday. To obtain funds to prepare for this invasion, he entered into a golf tournament with his human girlfriend as his caddy. He set up a factory off somewhere to make spaceships to prepare for the invasion.

Apparently the alien learned to play golf by watching TV and also just copying the movements of pros. He was a quick study. From what I remember, he didn't want to sell too much gold in case people got suspicious as to where he was getting all his gold. He also was investing in stocks; he was rich but needed even more money and the golf thing was supposed to be cover for how he got so rich. I forget if he was preparing defense of the Earth against his own kind or a separate alien civilization his kind was at war with.

Comment: Where did the alien learn to play golf? Why couldn't he raise enough money by turning things into gold? Was his spaceship factory on earth? How were the alien invaders going to get to earth without spaceships? Were the made-on-earth spaceships going to fly themselves to the alien planet?

Comment: Were the alien invaders planning a *military* invasion of earth, with guns and bombs and gas and rays? Or were they planning to *buy* the place with their artificial gold and prize money from winning golf tournaments etc.?

Comment: @KimOiler this bounty might get you an answer